# Using "where" syntax to parametrize a function in Julia

Tags: julia

Reading the Julia [documentation on parametric methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1), I can't for the life of me figure out the difference between these two definitions

```julia
julia> function f{T<:Real}(x::T)
    println("$x with type $T")
end


julia> function g(x::T) where {T<:Real}
    println("$x with type $T")
end
```

Any guidance on the semantic difference between these two definitions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The former is deprecated (in most instances) for the latter. `where` replaces the old syntax in v0.7 and onwards, and the first will not exist in 1.0.

One exception is inner constructors. The first syntax will still exist for them. But in that case type parameters means something very different. Example: `Array{Float64,2}()` the inner constructor takes in the parameters from the user. This was confusing before because type parameters had a dual meaning for these different constructs, but now this way of parameterizing only exists for inner constructors and only means this, whereas everything else uses `where`.